# How to re use access token for future request and how to refresh access token Android Outlook API

Tags: android, outlook, outlook-restapi

In the example OutlookQuickStart for Android works fine in the first request after logon().
Now I want to keep connect my app to that user and continue checking for new emails.. 
How can I re use the access token and build the request to check for new emails? 
Do I have to save the access token, refresh token ? 

How I can refresh the token in Android if it is expired.

Comment: Can you provide a link to this quick start?

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android

Comment: I saw that the _client has the data to call future request, How can I store it ? to reuse in a Service ?

Comment: That's a good question. I'm not familiar enough with the ADAL Android library to tell. Usually ADAL caches this information and handles refresh and everything for you, but I'm not sure if Android version does that. Let me see if I can track down the owner for it and get some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for the auth library at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android, the library caches the token and refresh token for you. So you would just use `acquireTokenSilentSync` to get the token each time you need it. That function would return the current token from the cache if it is still valid, and would refresh it if it is expired.

**UPDATE**: I've taken a closer look at the sample you're using and the Outlook SDK that it uses. The key thing here is the `DependencyResolver` object. You pass that object to the `OutlookClient` constructor. Then anytime you make an API call with that `OutlookClient`, it just calls the `getCredentials` override that you supply when you create the `DependencyResolver`.

So as the sample stands, you should be able to make multiple calls through that `OutlookClient` without having to change it at all. However, after an hour, when the access token expires, calls will start to fail. The fix for that would be to change the `getCredentials` override to always call `acquireTokenSilentSync`. Something like:

```
@Override
public Credentials getCredentials() {
    logger.debug("getCredentials in resolver called");

    AuthenticationResult result = mAuthContext.acquireTokenSilentSync(
        scopes, 
        getResources().getString(R.string.AADClientId), 
        UserIdentifier.getAnyUser());

    logger.debug("AcquireTokenSilentSync SUCCESS");
    logger.debug("Token expires: ", result.getExpiresOn());
    logger.debug("Token: ", result.getAccessToken());
    return new OAuthCredentials(result.getAccessToken());
}
```

> **Caveat**: I'm unable to run this code to validate it due to problems getting the Android emulator running on my dev machine :(.

Comment: Ok, lest try that. I have: Futures.addCallback(**_client**.getMe().getMailFolder("inbox").getMessages().top(5).read(), new FutureCallback<List<Message>>() {
_client has the info of the token... 
acquireTokenSilentSync is in _authToken so do you have an example to recover the _client values to use in the request ?

Comment: From the link I paste (OutlookQuickStart) _authContext.acquireTokenSilentSync(scopes, clientId from adal_settings.xml, and I am missing where to get the UserIdentifier user )

Comment: acquireTokenSilentSync is in the auth context, not the token. :)

Comment: ADAL docs say: Note: userId required in silent call is the one you get back from the interactive call) as parameter. Check the AuthenticationResult, maybe it's in there?

Comment: from AuthenticationResult I could get: AuthenticationResult.getInfoUser().getUniqueId() a String **but** UserIdentifier is not a String; UserIdentifier  required 'com.microsoft.aad.adal.UserIdentifier' according Android Studio.

Comment: so, from example of quick start every time I need to make a request I must to call the logon() changing his acquireTokenSilentSync instead of new AuhenticationContext?
And, inside logo(), if(_authContext != null ) make a acquireToken..Sync.... but there in getCredentials() return new OAuthCredentials... is that process correct to get the _client to reuse the token to make a new request?

Comment: Error from  
acquireTokenSilentSync : Refresh token is failed and prompt is not allowed , how with _authContext I get the _client to make the request?

Comment: Maybe this sample will help you: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-android

Comment: Doesn't clarify the error, Waiting for advices from Jason

Comment: @dstrockis Can you post an example about make the second request with acquireTokenSilentSync for Android?

Comment: Does the AcquireTokenSilentAsync call in this file help you? https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/blob/dev/sample/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal/hello/MainActivity.java

Comment: AcquireTokenSilent with the Async test is not the same of AcquireTokenSilentSync right?. <br/>
From this example [link](github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-SDK-Android) creating a new class can you call **AcquireTokenSilentSync** to get the credentials for a new request? and can you show the code?

Comment: @dsrockis Did you try your link with the Outlook-SDK-Android  ?

Comment: it seems that your sdk version ( about azure-activedirectory-...) is older than the link I provide.